# How to check if method is executed via a yield/block.call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a very basic example I have two Rails form helpers `toggles` and `checkbox`. I want the markup for the checkboxes different when they are inside the toggles block. I tried to use a instance variable to check if I'm inside the `toggles` method but someone said maintaining state like this would break the ability for this to be used in multithreaded applications. What would be a better way?

So basically I want to check if I'm inside `toggles` when `checkbox` is executed.

```
<%= toggles 'Select one' do %>
  <%= f.checkbox 'Foo' %>
  <%= f.checkbox 'Bar' %>
  <%= f.checkbox 'Baz' %>
<% end %>

def toggles(*args)
  @inside_toggles = true
  template.concat yield
  @inside_toggles = false
end

def checkbox(*args)
  if @inside_toggles
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: You can check/track the current method name using the [`__method__`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__) or [`__callee__`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__) methods.. Give it a try.

Comment: Both give the method name that was called. `puts __callee_` inside `checkbox` prints "checkbox".

Comment: You did it wrong, that's why? place one `puts __callee__` inside the `checkbox` and the other one in `toggles`.. then you can see the switch... Give it a try.

Comment: Sure? If I read the documentation correct they both return the name of the -current- method.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a formatting issue, did you try using CSS?

You add a class for helper method `toggles`

```
def toggles
  content_tag :div, class: 'toggle'
end
```

Then in your CSS

```
.toggle input[type="checkbox"] {
   /* special format */
}
```

Comment: Good idea but I need the markup to be different for the checkbox.